# Some function not working when add GoogleMap API

Tags: google-maps

I refer to the sample code at [link](http://jsfiddle.net/geary/6qfhF/8/)

It works fine but when I add the Google Map API on the `html` tag

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=My_API_Key">
```

It's only draw the Map but not draw marker. 
How can I draw the marker and add My Google Map API follow this code

Comment: `ReferenceError: google is not defined` means you are trying to use the Google Maps Javascript API v3 before it is loaded (your code is using `async defer`; you probably should remove that).

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the gmap at window level

```
var data = [
   [ 'First_loc', '36.95781,36.63568' ],
   [ 'Second_loc', '36.88827,36.636908' ]
];

var gmap;
```

and in your  HTMLMarker function add  the marker creation

```
function HTMLMarker( place ) {
  var latLngStrings = place[1].split(',');
  var lat = +latLngStrings[0];
  var lng = +latLngStrings[1];
  this.name = place[0];
  this.pos = new google.maps.LatLng( lat, lng );
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng( lat, lng ),
      map: gmap,
      title: 'Hello World!'
    });

 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/geary/6qfhF/8/

and remove the var declaration for gmap  inside the initialize() function

Comment: thanks for your help. But when I add `<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=My_API_Key">` on the `header`. It not working

Comment: Are you sure you have a valid  apikey   ??   .. have you error in console ?? what mean don't work  ?   .. ..

Comment: It is an error : `ReferenceError: google is not defined`

Comment: This mean that you have not loaded  (properly ) the google apis ..  so .. check better for your link and for your  valid google maps api key...